# Need to see what printers are connected to x amount of machines. Machine names stored in a text file call Computers.txt

Tags: vbscript

I need assistance with reading machine names out of a file and listing the printers connected to those machines. Here I list my variables

```
Const ForAppending = 8
Const ForReading = 1
Dim WshNetwork, objPrinter, intDrive, intNetLetter, fso
```

Here I define my input file text file

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set InputFile = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\xVBS Scripts\Computers.txt", 1)
strComputer = InputFile.ReadAll

Set WshNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colInstalledPrinters = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Printer")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem",,48)
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each objItem in colItems
  UserName = objItem.UserName
  arrUserName = Split(UserName, "\", -1, 1)
  varUserName = arrUserName(1)
Next
```

Here I define my output file which I later open automatically

```
filOutput = varUserName & ".txt"

If objFSO.FileExists(filOutput) Then
  objFSO.DeleteFile(filOutput)
End If

Set objOutputFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile (filOutput, ForAppending, True)
For Each objPrinter In colInstalledPrinters
  strTest = Left(objPrinter.Name, 2)
  objOutputFile.WriteLine(objPrinter.Name)
Next


Set objPrinter = WshNetwork.EnumPrinterConnections
If objPrinter.Count = 0 Then
  WScript.Echo "No Printers Mapped "
Else
  For intDrive = 0 To (objPrinter.Count -1) Step 2
    intNetLetter = IntNetLetter + 1
    printer = "UNC Path " & objPrinter.Item(intDrive) & " = " & objPrinter.Item(intDrive +1) & " Printer : " & intDrive
    objOutputFile.WriteLine(printer)
  Next
End If
objOutputFile.Close

Wscript.Sleep 1500 
MsgBox "Printer mapping report is located" & vbNewLine & "in the following directory: " &  filOutput , vbInformation, "Report Located At"

WshShell.Run "Notepad " & filOutput, 1, False

Wscript.Quit
```

Comment: and exactly what is wrong with this code?

Comment: I can't figure out how to get it to read more than a single line from the text file. I know I need to use a loop but I am not sure which kind and what code to encase into the loop. I am a beginner level scripter and I am learning as I go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reading the entire file into the variable `strComputer`:

```
Set InputFile = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\xVBS Scripts\Computers.txt", 1)
strComputer = InputFile.ReadAll
                        ^^^^^^^
```

If you want to process the file line by line you need something like this:

```
Set InputFile = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\xVBS Scripts\Computers.txt")
For Each strComputer In Split(InputFile.ReadAll, vbNewLine)
  ...
Next
InputFile.Close
```

or (better) like this:

```
Set InputFile = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\xVBS Scripts\Computers.txt")
Do Until InputFile.AtEndOfStream
  strComputer = InputFile.ReadLine
  ...
Loop
InputFile.Close
```